# Encrypt and Decrypt between two application

Tags: java, encryption

I am looking for a way to pass encrypted message between two applications. Let's say I have two Java applications App1 and App2. App1 need to encrypt the message and dump on place where App2 can pick it up. App2 have X509 certificate so App1 can get public key (from App1's .cert file) and decrypt the message. However I am not able to fig out how can App2 itself decrypt message using the .cert file. On first place is providing App2's .cert file to App1 is security risk?

What other options I can have if I want to have asymmetric encryption since I do not want to share a common secret key.

TIA

Comment: App 2 will need the private key associated with the public key in its certificate to decrypt. You will have created the private key when you created the certificate. (Do you need a certificate wrapping the public key? You may just want to share the public key.)

Comment: You would pass the public key, for decrypting.  If the private key is shared then it would break the security.